# Routes, gems and generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have written a gem with an install generator. I would like to use this generator to add routes to the `config/routes.rb` file, much in the same way as the devise gem does by adding `devise_for :model_name`. Therefore, I need to know how to:

Make a method (like `devise_for`) available within the scope of routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've figured it out. To add to the routes file you can use the method `route` in the generator. I have accomplished this by adding the following to my install_generator.rb file:

```
def setup_routes
  route("add_gem_routes")
end
```

Note that I am in fact calling a method, which can be added to the scope of routes by defining it in the following namespace:

```
module ActionDispatch::Routing
  class Mapper
    def add_gem_routes
      #routing code...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: was just answering! well, +1 :)